# search result die and redirect

Tags: php, sql, redirect, die

hi i want to know one thing
i have site and i want that when people search for a specific keyword and if the results are not available for that specific keyword on my site then it shows error message and redirect back to index.php

currently i am using this

die("Search Result Not Found");

it only show the error message but not redirect back to index.php please help me with the code that kill the sql query and redirect to index.php

Answer (score 0):

definition of [die()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php):

> die — Equivalent to exit

So, no operation will be performed after `die()`